# contact form 7 conditional required checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a conditional form ( Contact Form 7 on Wordpress) which will hide or show fields according to the boxes checked on the first question.

Only the questions showing up are `required` (i.e. their categories were checked in the first question). In order to do that, I need to set the all the checkboxes as `required` and then perform the magic at the validation code below

```
function wpcf7_checkbox_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
$tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );


$type = $tag->type;
$name = $tag->name;

$value = isset( $_POST[$name] ) ? (array) $_POST[$name] : array();

if ( $tag->is_required() && empty( $value ) ) {
    $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) );
}

return $result;
}
```

for this particular line `if ( $tag->is_required() && empty( $value ) )` I need to change it to check:

1. `$tag->required()` AND
2. `empty( $value )` AND
3. whether the checkbox's main category has been checked

Only then will it be invalidated.

How can the 3rd point be coded? Also I have about 5-10 questions for each category.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after much effort

```
function example_checkbox_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
$tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );

$arr1 = array('project', 'property', 'budget', 'spaces', 'physical-limitations', 'achieve', 'control', 'lighting', 'climate', 'security');
$arr2 = array('pc_room', 'pc_display', 'pc_audio', 'pc_source', 'pc_seat', 'pc_control');

$type = $tag->type;
$name = $tag->name;

$value = isset( $_POST[$name] ) ? (array) $_POST[$name] : array();

foreach($_POST['choice'] as $selected){
    if ( $selected == 'Example' ) {
        if ( $tag->is_required() && empty( $value ) ) {
            foreach ($arr1 as $array) {
                    if ( $name == $array ) {
                        $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ( $selected == 'Example 2' ) {
        if ( $tag->is_required() && empty( $value ) ) {
            foreach ($arr2 as $array) {
                    if ( $name == $array ) {
                        $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return $result;
```

}